# how to check device capability

Tags: java, android, cordova

How to check the device capability for android cordova?can anyone provide a code ?  error with context variable..shows context variable is null at this location ,while trying to run the code in device showing force close!! am trying to check camera capability..please help...thanks in advance

```
package com.troubling.android;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws
    JSONException 
    {
        Context context = null;
        PackageManager  pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();


        if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {


            Log.i("camera", "This device has camera!");
        }
        else{

            Log.i("camera", "This device has no camera!");
        }

return false;

    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
PackageManager  pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
```